# Proof of nilpotent matrix in Complex Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

n $\in \mathbb N$  V is a n-dimensional Vectorspace of $ \mathbb C$ and $\phi$ is a endomorphism of V with $$ im(\phi) \subseteq ker(\phi)$$

Prove that $\phi$ is nilpotent.

Additionally find dependent of $rank(\phi)$ :

Characterstic polynomial, minimal polynomial and jordan normal form of $\phi$.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? Just do it! If you apply $\phi$ to any vector from $V$ what do you get? And if you apply $\phi$ once more what do you get then? For the minimal polynomial you have to take care of the special case ${\rm im}(\phi)=\{\mathbf0\}$, i.e., ${\rm rank}\phi = 0$.

Comment: I don't know how to prove.. What does $im(\phi) \subseteq ker(\phi)$ mean? What should I do with it?

Comment: Do you know what the *notations* im($\varphi)$ and ker($\varphi)$ mean? Do you know what it means for one to be a subset of the other?

Comment: I'm not sure of $im(\phi)$, I know the others.

Comment: ${\rm im}(\phi)$ is the full image of $\phi$, i.e., ${\rm im}(\phi)=\phi(V) = \{\phi(v)| v\in V\}$.

Comment: Note, that you should show some effort to solve the homework and ask specific questions to the part which you do not understand. I think that is the reason why somebody (not me) down-voted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We can deduce from the information given that $\phi^2=0$

Comment: How do we know that?

Comment: $\phi^2(v)=\phi(\phi(v))$. But $\phi(v)\in im(\phi) \subseteq \ker(\phi)$. By definition, this means...